# How to set httpstate in httpcompnents

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am updating httpclient version in my project. The current version of httpclient is httpclient3.2 I need to upgrade this to 4.x(httpcomponents). I was able to do lot of changes through [this](http://debuguide.blogspot.in/2013/01/quick-guide-for-migration-of-commons.html) url.But confused to set the httpstate. In httpclient 3.x version , following code has used to set the http version

```
  PoolingClientConnectionManager connMgr =new PoolingClientConnectionManager();
  connMgr.setDefaultMaxPerRoute( m_maxConnectionsPerHost );

    // Create a new HttpState container
    HttpState initialState = new HttpState();
    m_client = new DefaultHttpClient(connMgr);
    m_client.setState( initialState );
```

what will be the equivalent API for HttpState which can I use to set httpstate in httpclient4.x(httpcomponents). I googled about it but not cleared.
Thanks in advance for help.